# Building a collaborative tool - Checking if a user is currently editing/dragging elements and display dialog

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, user-interface

Hi after some ideas really,

I have built a drag n drop collaborative tool (kinda like a mood board) for people to post ideas to collaborate on. All powered by AJAX through Jquery UI, Jquery with PHP/Mysql handling position and data storage. My question is this say I have 2 users. User 1 drags and resizes an image and moves it - user 2 drags the same image, user 1 will then see their image move and pop up where user 2 placed.

Can I detect user 1's ajax call or an edit or drag from them and then say have a dialog box to say "being edited" or something along those lines to user 2? If so how would I go about this?

Hope my babbling makes sense? I have an image attached to help illustrate my point.

Many thanks in advance![image]

Comment: How do you currently handle sending updates to the clients? Do you use polling?

Comment: I think the only way to do that would be to have user 1's window constantly poll the server for changes every x amount of time. You can limit it to when the window has focus so that it doesn't do it indefinitely in a background window.

Comment: cheers for the comments guys taking it all on board!

Answer (score 1):

you could use the start-event of draggable

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   start: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

and lock the item for dragging for other users. just create a column "draggedBy" and put the username who is currently dragging it, and NULL otherwise.

if you like this approach you might want to put a timeout of a few seconds to not lock the item forever if the user, who owns the lock disconnects. you could create a second column draggingStartedAt, and put the current timestamp in it. now just mind this lock if it is not older than MAX_LOCK_TIME, maybe 10s, or something.

if you need something more complex, there are many locking methods out there: [Wikipedia: Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: cool the option of stopping drags was one I considered but was unsure who to implement it.  This shoulds like a big step in right direction cheers!

Comment: You'd have probably needed to prevent other dragging no matter what, as others might still try and drag and item that's moving in front of them. Never trust the user to normal things ;)

Comment: @Ben Griffiths - yeah users are strange beasts!